# How do you work out the sum of the series: $\cos{x}+\cos{2x}+\cdots+\cos{(n-1)x}$ by multiplying through by $2\sin(x/2)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do you work out the sum of the series: $\cos{x}+\cos{2x}+\cdots+\cos{(n-1)x}$ by multiplying through by $2\sin(x/2)$? I am supposed to find the sum using only this method and I'm not completely sure what the sum at the end would look like. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: @Adam: Why not post that as an answer? I'd up-vote it.

Comment: Adam gave you the correct answer.
Another way is to use that $$e^{ix}+e^{2ix}+\cdots+e^{(n-1)ix}=e^{ix}\dfrac{e^{(n-1)ix}-1}{e^{ix}-1}$$ and [Euler's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_identity#Explanation).

Comment: @Pambos: You didn't need to delete your answer. It's OK to have multiple answers showing different ways of solving a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Use identity $$2\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) = \sin(\theta + \phi)-\sin(\theta-\phi)$$

Comment: Style: the \ is missing from the second sine! I tried to put that in but it wouldn't let me! :[

Comment: @Artist Thanks, corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use that $$e^{ix}+e^{2ix}+\cdots+e^{(n-1)ix}=e^{ix}\dfrac{e^{(n-1)ix}-1}{e^{ix}-1}$$ and [Euler's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity#Explanation).